# Do I always have `(a / b * b) + a % b == a` when b is not zero?

Tags: c++, c

For `int a, b`, I know that when there is exactly one of `a` and `b` is negative, the result of `a / b` and `a % b` is machine dependent. But do I always have `(a / b * b) + a % b == a` when `b` is not zero?

Comment: What do you mean by `always have` and what types are a and b

Comment: Indeed, if the type is an unsigned type, the equality always holds when `b` is nonzero.

Comment: Where can I find a demonstration?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C++11 §5.6[expr.mul]/4 specifies:

> If the quotient `a/b` is representable in the type of the result, `(a/b)*b + a%b` is equal to `a`.

C11 §6.5.5/6 specifies the same with slightly different phrasing:

> If the quotient `a/b` is representable, the expression `(a/b)*b + a%b` shall equal `a`; otherwise, the behavior of both `a/b` and `a%b` is undefined.

Comment: Note that the "if the quotient is representable" clause is essential. For example if `a==INT_MIN` and `b==-1`, the equality is false (and the behavior is undefined).

Comment: @R.. - this is true for twos-complement representation, but not for sign-magnitude. Not sure about ones-complement. All three are valid integer representations for C and C++.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it's false in general, since twos complement is a possibility. It's also false in practice, since ones complement and sign/magnitude implementations do not exist.